# HTMX pass button value from selected list

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates, htmx

I'm trying to make an application with Django using htmx.
I have created a dropdown list as:

```
<select class="custom-select mb-4" name="fields" hx-get="{% url 'select_field' %}" hx-trigger="change" hx-target="#Wells">
            <option selected>Select a field</option>
            {% for Field in TFTFields %}
            <option ue="{{Field.Perimeter}}">{{Field.Perimeter}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

Now I want to take the selected value from this list and pass it to a button to excite another function called "plotlybar", I did something like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" hx-get="{% url 'plotlybar' %}" hx-target="#plotlybar">Plot the bar Well Serv</button>
```

So now I didn't know how to pass this selected items?
any hints or solution?

All my best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include additional form elements in a HTMX request via [`hx-include` attribute](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-include/) that uses CSS query selectors:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" 
        hx-get="{% url 'plotlybar' %}"
        hx-include="[name='fields']"
        hx-target="#plotlybar">
  Plot the bar Well Serv
</button>
```

If you want to include multiple elements, provide a comma separated list of selectors, e.g.: `[name='field1'], [name='field2']`.

Comment: Many thanks, and I received the input in the view.py as : Field = request.GET.get('fields')