# Toggle Switch Button using HTMX

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates, htmx

is there any method to use Toggle Switch Button with HTMX?

if there, I need to pass a value to another button like my previous question.
the Toggle Button is named 'Toggle' and have two (on/off) values and I need to pass them as:

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary" 
         hx-get="{% url 'plotlybar' %}"
         hx-include="[name='fields'],[name='Toggle']"
         hx-target="#plotlybar">   Plot the bar Well Serv </button>
```

[My previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984443/htmx-pass-button-value-from-selected-list)

So how to get this Button with HTMX
All my best

Comment: Sure, the toggle button is just a fancy radio input element. This code looks fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I used this 
`<label class="switch"><input type="checkbox"  name="Toggle"><span class="slider round"></span></label>` with its scripts and it works, I just want if there simple one with HTMX, many thanks

Comment: You mean the switch button has some custom JS that handles e.g. the switch animation and setting the value of the checkbox input? Part of it is still required because HTMX is not for that kind of frontend interactivity where there's no communication between the frontend and backend. HTMX submits a request to the backend and replaces part of the page with the returned rendered content.

Comment: Yes, but I just need none or on to be sent to the backend that's all with a button in frontend. the above solution submits a request to the backend that has none or on values. anyway many thanks.

Comment: If I understand your question and you want to use htmx, you need the oob Out of the bands response technique. You must have 2 views and 2 templates. From point A you go to point B. from point B you return to point A. Point A and point B are your button. The user has the impression of clicking the same button. The button text and views change in dynamic way. Search for tutorials on the oob technique and see if it's right for you. I hope to be proved helpful.